# Get specific match of a key in nested python lists

Tags: python

I want to get key value of `Name` and `Value` from the below variable using Python.

```
a = [
  {
    "Route53": [
      [
        {
          "Name": "xyz.net.",
          "ResourceRecords": [
            {
              "Value": "1.1.1.1"
            }
          ],
          "TTL": 600,
          "Type": "A"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: `a[0]['Route53'][0][0]['Name']` and `a[0]['Route53'][0][0]['ResourceRecords'][0]['Value']`

Comment: Your object is a list, access its first element to obtain the dictionary. Start with `a[0]["Route53"]` What do you obtain? A list again. Keep going to obtain your values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
new_final_data = [[b for a, b in i.items()][0][0][0] for i in a]
output = [{"Name":i["Name"], 'Value':i['ResourceRecords'][0]["Value"]} for i in new_final_data]
```

Output:

```
[{'Name': 'xyz.net.', 'Value': '1.1.1.1'}]
```

Comment: Thanks Ajax. Can you pls explain your code how it is working am new for python, Thanks in advance. Can you pls refer link/Book to learn this kinds of nested list and dictionary.

Comment: @Jai this code is utilizing list comprehension to create a list of dictionaries. By iterating over each dictionary in the data list, we can access the values that are necessary by passing the key value to the dictionary. Here is a link to learn more about comprehensions: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk. Also, if this answer assisted you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very odd variable, but you can do the following to get the `Name`:

```
a[0]['Route53'][0][0]['Name']
```

And the following to get the `Value`:

```
a[0]['Route53'][0][0]['ResourceRecords'][0]['Value']
```

I'm not sure if that answers your question?

**Note:** This is an inadvertent copy of Avihoo Mamka's comment to the OP.  Sorry for not noticing.

Comment: Thank you @Miraj50.  Very embarrassing, but I hadn't noticed that comment -- I should be more careful.